# Avoiding creating media bundles for single files with django-mediagenerator

Tags: django, django-mediagenerator

One small issue that I have been having with [Django-Mediagenerator](https://django-mediagenerator.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) is that when using the `include_media` tag...

```
{% load media %}
{% include_media 'my_style.css' %}
```

... an error is thrown unless the `my_style.css` media bundle exists. However, in some cases, this would mean that my media bundle contains only one file.

Is there a way to avoid creating media bundles for individual files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that there is no way to do this using Django-mediagenerator. The only way to do this would be to use static-files for some parts, and media bundles for others (defeating the purpose of using Django-mediagenerator).